NeutronAdminCredentialConfigurationInvalid and errors 400,401, 500
I have a deployment of OpenStack in our cluster with a provider network configured. We launched an Instance a while ago although since last week we are not able to retrieve instance data from Horizon or the OpenStack API.
Going through the logs on both Controller and Compute node, we collected the following errors:
CONTROLLER:
                        nova-api.log:
                                - 2024-09-02 10:52:59.851 54640 INFO nova.api.openstack.requestlog [...] 10.0.0.1 "GET /v2.1/servers/detail?limit=21&project_id=332f0702092741ff8e12ee4658a33c09&sort_dir=desc&sort_dir=desc&sort_dir=desc&sort_key=created_at&sort_k>
                                - [pid: 54640|app: 0|req: 1/3] 10.0.0.1 () {34 vars in 988 bytes} [Mon Sep  2 10:52:49 2024] GET /v2.1/servers/detail?limit=21&project_id=332f0702092741ff8e12ee4658a33c09&sort_
                                dir=desc&sort_dir=desc&sort_dir=desc&sort_key=created_at&sort_key=display_name&sort_key=uuid => generated 104 bytes in 10551 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 7 headers in 343 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
                                - 2024-09-02 10:52:59.842 54640 ERROR nova.network.neutron [None req-2c374342-0aef-484f-8878-4bf57b34d7cb 7d929138651a4a5aa75517fecdf4b49c 332f0702092741ff8e12ee4658a33c09 - -
                                default default] Neutron client was not able to generate a valid admin token, please verify Neutron admin credential located in nova.conf: neutronclient.common.exceptions.
                                Unauthorized: 401-{'error': {'code': 401, 'title': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'The request you have made requires authentication.'}}
                                - 2024-09-02 10:49:05.064 54636 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Deprecated: Option "auth_strategy" from group "api" is deprecated for removal (
                                  2024-09-02 10:49:05.346 54636 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Deprecated: Option "api_servers" from group "glance" is deprecated for removal (

                        apache2/error.log:
                                - [Mon Sep 02 10:52:59.861119 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 54433:tid 274466857248] [client 10.100.4.35:55124] WARNING horizon.exceptions Recoverable error: Networking client is
                                experiencing an unauthorized exception. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-2c374342-0aef-484f-8878-4bf57b34d7cb),
                                referer: https://licheenostrum.int.bsc.es/horizon/auth/login/?next=/horizon/project/instances/
                                - [Mon Sep 02 14:00:48.396856 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 54434:tid 274315788576] [client 10.100.4.94:52630] DEBUG novaclient.v2.client RESP BODY:
                                {"computeFault": {"code": 500, "message": "Unexpected API Error.
                                Please report this at http://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/ and attach the Nova API log if possible.\\n<class 'nova.exception.NeutronAdminCredentialConfigurationInvalid'>"}},
                                referer: https://licheenostrum.int.bsc.es/horizon/project/
                                - [Mon Sep 02 10:53:02.640401 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 54433:tid 274466857248] [client 10.100.4.35:55124] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_policy/policy.py:1588:
                                DeprecationWarning: identity:create_identity_provider deprecated without deprecated_reason or deprecated_since. This will be an error in a future release,
                                referer: https://licheenostrum.int.bsc.es/horizon/auth/login/?next=/horizon/project/instances/
                                - [Mon Sep 02 10:53:11.440085 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 54433:tid 274466857248] [client 10.100.4.35:55124] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_policy/policy.py:1588:
                                DeprecationWarning: update_trunk deprecated without deprecated_reason or deprecated_since. This will be an error in a future release,
                                referer: https://licheenostrum.int.bsc.es/horizon/auth/login/?next=/horizon/project/instances/
                                - [Mon Sep 02 10:53:11.401337 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 54433:tid 274466857248] [client 10.100.4.35:55124] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_policy/policy.py:1588:
                                DeprecationWarning: delete_security_group deprecated without deprecated_reason or deprecated_since. This will be an error in a future release,
                                referer: https://licheenostrum.int.bsc.es/horizon/auth/login/?next=/horizon/project/instances/

                        neutron-api.log:
                                - 2024-09-02 10:46:45.400 54307 CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: KeyError: 'formatters'
                                - 2024-09-02 10:46:45.513 54309 CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: LookupError: No section 'main' (prefixed by 'app' or 'application' or 'composite' or 'composit' or
                                'pipeline' or 'filter-app') found in config /etc/neutron/api-paste.ini
                                - [pid: 54539|app: 0|req: 53/277] 10.0.0.14 () {34 vars in 1038 bytes} [Mon Sep  2 13:06:29 2024] GET /v2.0/ports?device_id=0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597&fields=
                                binding%3Ahost_id&fields=binding%3Avif_type => generated 114 bytes in 1976 msecs (HTTP/1.1 401) 4 headers in 204 bytes (1 switches on core 5)
                                - 2024-09-02 10:49:24.428 54540 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [None req-f3d90c96-d832-463a-adf3-4506574eca38 - - - - - -] Configuring www_authenticate_uri to point
                                to the public identity endpoint is required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint



COMPUTE:
                        nova-compute.log:
                                - 2024-09-05 13:22:58.318 3592379 ERROR nova.compute.manager nova.exception.InvalidDiskInfo: Disk info file is invalid:
                                qemu-img failed to execute on /var/lib/nova/instances/0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597/disk : Unexpected error while running command.
                                - 2024-09-05 13:22:58.318 3592379 ERROR nova.compute.manager Stderr: "qemu-img: Could not open '/var/lib/nova/instances/0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597/disk':
                                Could not open '/var/lib/nova/instances/0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597/disk': Permission denied\n"
                                - 2024-09-05 13:24:27.741 3592379 ERROR nova.network.neutron [None req-6b2ff8da-eb8f-4bfb-bf86-6617588c243a - - - - - -] Neutron client was not able to generate a valid admin
                                token, please verify Neutron admin credential located in nova.conf: neutronclient.common.exceptions.Unauthorized: 401-{'error': {'code': 401, 'title': 'Unauthorized', 'message':
                                'The request you have made requires authentication.'}}

It seems to be an authentication issue and/or lack of neutron credentials when it makes the call to nova.
I went through nova, neutron and keystone config files several times, comparing them to OpenStacks' documentation and making sure it fits our specific scenario, nonetheless here's our relevant nova.conf (which some logs pointed to it) and neutron.conf configurations.
# neutron.conf #

# Complete Identity API endpoint.
auth_url = http://10.0.0.1:5000/v3

# Project name for auth.
project_name = test

# The region in which the identity server can be found. (string value)
region_name = RegionOne


# Project's domain name for auth.
project_domain_name = Default

# Username for auth.
username = neutron

# User's domain name for auth
user_domain_name = Default

# Password for auth
password = foo


# nova.conf #

[neutron]

default_floating_pool = ext-net
service_metadata_proxy = true
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = foo

auth_type = password
auth_url = http://10.0.0.1:5000/v3
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = test
username = neutron
user_domain_name = Default
password = foo
service_name = neutron


More configurations that might be useful:
# openvswitch_agent.ini #

integration_bridge = br-int
tunnel_bridge = br-tun
local_ip = "10.0.0.1"
bridge_mappings = provider:br-provider
firewall_driver = openvswitch
enable_security_group = True
enable_ipset = True

# ml2_conf.ini #

type_drivers = flat,vlan,local
tenant_network_types = local
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch
extension_drivers = port_security
flat_networks = provider


